# Incorrect result in LLVM Alias Analysis

Tags: llvm

I want to check if the values a and b in the  program alias.

```
int main() { 
int *a,*b; 
a=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
b=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
*a=10;
*b=8;
return 0;
 }
```

I use the below code for this (getAnalysisUsage method has been defined)

```
AliasAnalysis::Location loc1=AliasAnalysis::Location(k1);  //a
AliasAnalysis::Location loc2=AliasAnalysis::Location(k2);  //b
AliasAnalysis::AliasResult ar=AA.alias(loc1,loc2);
```

But I get ar=1 i.e May Alias result. Where am I going wrong? I have
included -basicaa option in the opt command for running this.

Comment: Isn't aliasing a pointer thing? The docs always mention pointers, not plain variables.

Comment: Seems the same problem as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9602792/alias-analysis-in-llvm

try with a different alias analyzis.