# Incorrect LLVM alias analysis

Tags: llvm, alias, static-analysis, llvm-ir

I'm asking a question similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9999623/incorrect-result-in-llvm-alias-analysis) about an LLVM alias analysis that seems to give incorrect results.
Since it contains considerable re-writing,
I have decided to post it as a separate question.
I'm running this very simple code:

```
char *foo()
{
    int i;
    int size;
    char *s=malloc(5);
    char *p=malloc(8);

    while ((i < size) && (s < p))
    {
        i--;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Every time my code runs into an `icmp` instruction, I ask whether
its operands can be aliases of one another. For the first comparison
it trivially answers no, but for the second comparison between
`%tmp2` and `%tmp3` it answers yes.
Here is the resulting LLVM bitcode:

```
; Function Attrs: nounwind uwtable
define internal i8* @foo() #0 {
entry:
  %i = alloca i32, align 4
  %s = alloca i8*, align 8
  %p = alloca i8*, align 8
  %size = alloca i32, align 4
  %call = call noalias i8* @malloc(i64 8) #3
  store i8* %call, i8** %s, align 8
  %call1 = call noalias i8* @malloc(i64 13) #3
  store i8* %call1, i8** %p, align 8
  br label %while.cond

while.cond:    ; preds = %while.body, %entry
  %tmp = load i32, i32* %i, align 4
  %tmp1 = load i32, i32* %size, align 4
  %cmp = icmp sgt i32 %tmp, %tmp1
  br i1 %cmp, label %land.rhs, label %while.end

land.rhs:    ; preds = %while.cond
  %tmp2 = load i8*, i8** %p, align 8
  %tmp3 = load i8*, i8** %s, align 8
  %cmp2 = icmp ult i8* %tmp2, %tmp3
  br i1 %cmp2, label %while.body, label %while.end

while.body:    ; preds = %land.rhs
  %tmp5 = load i32, i32* %i, align 4
  %dec = add nsw i32 %tmp5, -1
  store i32 %dec, i32* %i, align 4
  br label %while.cond

while.end:    ; preds = %while.cond, %land.rhs
  ret i8* null
}
```

When I looked at the specifications
of the pass `-basicaa` in [the LLVM documentation](https://llvm.org/docs/AliasAnalysis.html#the-basicaa-pass), it explicitly says that (emphasis mine):

> Distinct globals, stack allocations, and **heap allocations** can never alias.

But this is the case here, with two different heap allocations.
What's going on?

**EDIT**:

Here is the output of print-alias-sets

```
opt -basicaa -aa-eval -globals-aa -scev-aa -loop-simplify -instnamer -print-alias-sets -indvars -simplifycfg -view-cfg -o ./examples/input.ready.bc ./examples/input.bc
Alias Set Tracker: 4 alias sets for 4 pointer values.
  AliasSet[0x563ec3312a90, 1] must alias, Mod       Pointers: (i32* %argc.addr, 4)
  AliasSet[0x563ec3312b30, 1] must alias, Mod       Pointers: (i8*** %argv.addr, 8)
  AliasSet[0x563ec3312bd0, 1] must alias, Mod/Ref   Pointers: (i32* %i, 4)
  AliasSet[0x563ec3312c70, 2] may alias, Mod/Ref   Pointers: (i8* %arrayidx, 1)
  3 Unknown instructions: i8* %call, i32 %call1, i8* %call2

Alias Set Tracker: 3 alias sets for 3 pointer values.
  AliasSet[0x563ec3312a90, 1] must alias, Mod/Ref   Pointers: (i8** %lp.addr, 8)
  AliasSet[0x563ec3312b80, 1] must alias, Mod       Pointers: (i32* %size.addr, 4)
  AliasSet[0x563ec3312ae0, 1] must alias, Mod/Ref   Pointers: (i32* %i, 4)

Alias Set Tracker: 5 alias sets for 4 pointer values.
  AliasSet[0x563ec3312b80, 1] may alias, Mod/Ref   
  2 Unknown instructions: i8* %call, i8* %call1
  AliasSet[0x563ec3312bd0, 1] must alias, Mod/Ref   Pointers: (i8** %s, 8)
  AliasSet[0x563ec33129f0, 1] must alias, Mod/Ref   Pointers: (i8** %p, 8)
  AliasSet[0x563ec33229c0, 1] must alias, Mod/Ref   Pointers: (i32* %i, 4)
  AliasSet[0x563ec3322a60, 1] must alias, Ref       Pointers: (i32* %size, 4)

===== Alias Analysis Evaluator Report =====
  94 Total Alias Queries Performed
  73 no alias responses (77.6%)
  18 may alias responses (19.1%)
  2 partial alias responses (2.1%)
  1 must alias responses (1.0%)
  Alias Analysis Evaluator Pointer Alias Summary: 77%/19%/2%/1%
  54 Total ModRef Queries Performed
  17 no mod/ref responses (31.4%)
  0 mod responses (0.0%)
  3 ref responses (5.5%)
  34 mod & ref responses (62.9%)
  Alias Analysis Evaluator Mod/Ref Summary: 31%/0%/5%/62%
```

**ANOTHER EDIT**:

Here's how I check for aliasing from within the (Loop) pass:

```
virtual bool runOnLoop(Loop *loop, LPPassManager &LPM)
{       
    AA = &getAnalysis<AAResultsWrapperPass>().getAAResults();

    for (auto it = loop->block_begin(); it != loop->block_end(); it++)
    {
        for (auto inst = (*it)->begin(); inst != (*it)->end(); inst++)
        {
            Instruction *i = (Instruction *) inst;
            if (strncmp(i->getOpcodeName(),"icmp",4) == 0)
            {
                CmpInst *ci = (CmpInst *) i;
                if (AA->isNoAlias(
                    ci->getOperand(0),
                    ci->getOperand(1)))
                {
                    errs() << ci->getOperand(0)->getName().str();
                    errs() << " and ";
                    errs() << ci->getOperand(1)->getName().str();
                    errs() << " are NOT aliases\n";
                }
                else
                {
                    errs() << ci->getOperand(0)->getName().str();
                    errs() << " and ";
                    errs() << ci->getOperand(1)->getName().str();
                    errs() << " are aliases of one another\n";
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: what is the output of `opt -basicaa -print-alias-sets foo.bc`?

Comment: I added -print-alias-sets to opt flags and added the output to the post ... thanks

Comment: well, they are in different alias sets. how does the query happen in your pass? are you sure everything is proper?

Comment: compor thanks again ... I posted my runOnLoop and it prints: "tmp2 and tmp3 are aliases of one another" ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The different heap allocations are correctly regarded as separate (i.e. non-aliasing) and you can check that by adding this instruction at the end of the entry basic block:

```
%cmp3 = icmp ult i8* %call, %call1
```

For the alias analysis to properly "kick in", you need to run it over optimized code.
In this case also adding `-mem2reg` should do it.

Moreover, make sure that the function you're analyzing is not marked with the `optnone` attribute (disassemble and check in the readable IR code), which will disable optimizations for it.

Comment: Is it correct to say LLVM "forgot" that `*s` and `*p` point to return values of two `malloc()` calls (`%call` and `%call1`) which should never alias, due to lack of optimization in this case?

Comment: nah, I wouldn't anthropomorphize the compiler, it just does what we direct it to do.

Comment: -mem2reg solves the problem, but it does change the generated code completely. For my purpose it's perfectly fine, but I still wonder why `p` and `s` were aliased in the original code? About optimization, that did *not* work for me. And I'm not sure why optimization would help here?

Comment: could you maybe add a short explanation on the results of -print-alias-sets? it's not perfectly clear what goes on there, and the LLVM docs don't elaborate too much on it.

Comment: I'll amend with a short description on that when I get some time :-)